# Should we add tags in order to highlight techniques in an answer, that are not obviously related to the question?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Say you ask a question like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134383/why-is-this-group-not-free), which you believe should just be a matter of some group theory, so tag using a couple of relevant group theory tags, but you get an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1134552/29123) which ends up using algebraic topology. The question is not about algebraic topology, but algebraic topology ends up having interesting insight. The main purpose of tagging is to find and classify questions, but I can imagine using tags to find answers too.

> Should the tags on a question also reflect techniques used in answers? Would it be appropriate to add tags for that purpose?

Comment: As an aside, maybe a tag system for individual answers could be useful...

Comment: Yes, tags that are relevant in hindsight are still relevant. A person may ask something that is obviously an application of (say) Ramsey theory without realizing it. If someone else finds the question years later, the mere mention of the tag may be all they need. Someone looking at questions tagged Ramsey theory" may learn nice applications this way.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo If this was a buzz marketing campaign to check out [ramsey-theory], it worked :) More seriously, I agree with you. I am curious if people disagree, I could imagine someone wanting tags to say something about the questions in some strict sense, and not wanting tags to be "polluted" with answers. (Nice "seeing" you btw, sounds like at least a couple exciting things are happening. Congratulations on it all)

Comment: Thank you, Paul!

Comment: Note that while the accepted answer at the duplicate essentially says, "go ahead", the highest scored answer suggests otherwise.

Comment: Another related post: [Retagging after an answer is given](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612/retagging-after-an-answer-is-given). (Which seems to me closer to this question than the question which is [currently chosen as duplicate](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16681/about-extending-the-tag-system-to-answers-too).)